# Outline inside of a button

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to replicate this "subscribe to the newsletter button". I am having a hard time replicating the white "inside border or outline". 
[example of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFuX0.png)

Comment: It looks to me there are 2 elements at least. One outer and the inner has a white border.

Comment: box-shadow inset/outset is to be used here.

Comment: Another option : use `:before or :after`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this button styling with a combination of `border-radius` and `box-shadow`:

```css
button {
  background: darkcyan;
  border: 7px solid darkcyan;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;
}
```

```html
<button>Subscribe to newsletter</button>
```

With the `border` rule you set the outer border and with `border-radius` you round the corners. This will also effect the box-shadow, which will produce the inner white border line.

Answer (score 4):

You may use an inset shadow

```css
button {
  background:turquoise;
  border:solid turquoise;
  padding:5px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 3px white;
```

```html
<button>inside border ?</button>
```

You can also mix borders with inset and outset shadows http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/yJfjl ;)

Comment: thank you thank you! this worked perfectly!